# How to fetch data in magento as the product are not visible in grid view

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: product listing page with blank grids]

Here the all products are not visible. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: please share URL or describe the problem in detail

Comment: Are you looking for a php answer of how to retrieve all magento products or something?

Comment: @pooja have you re-indexed data from the index management?